# JSch lls command does not reflect directory change by lcd command

Tags: java, unix, sftp, jsch, working-directory

I'm working on an SFTP project in Java, using JSch library.

The code I'm currently using is: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html

The problem I have encountered is that:

My default local directory is something like this: `c:/users/myusername/jsch/` I change local directory with `lcd` command to `c:/`. After that I test it with `lpwd` which returns "Local working directory: C:\" as I've expected. But after that, I execute `lls` command, it lists directory in the beginning (`c:/users/myusername/jsch/`), not `c:/`.

Is this a bug in the library? Because I tried same commands with XShell, I got different result which I was expecting(after `lcd`, `lls` worked properly). If it's not a bug, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug.

An implementation of `lcd` command in the `Sftp.java` example calls into a `ChannelSftp.lcd()` method. The call changes a value of a field `ChannelSftp.lcwd`, which that can be retrieved using `ChannelSftp.lpwd()` method.

But an implementation of `lls` command does not use `ChannelSftp` at all, not even its `ChannelSftp.lpwd()`, so it always lists an actual local working directory of the process, not the "virtual" local working directory of `ChannelSftp`.

Solutions:

- fix the `Sftp.java` to use `ChannelSftp.lpwd()` or
- use absolute paths.

Comment: Fixing **Sftp.java** to use **ChannelSftp.lpwd()** solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Martin Prikryl I'm using absolute paths, but still it is not working. Look like it doesnt work with absolute paths.

Comment: @AnilReddyYarragonda It's a different problem. Ask a new question.